# Misplaced colours in map for ggplot R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to plot a map using ggplot. I am able to successfully get the plot for an Indian state UP. I am using population of two regions Lucknow and Allahabad (High court bench) as fill for colour. The plot comes up beautifully but colour for two districts is switched "Lucknow" and "Lalitpur" as seen in the plot below.[image: State plot with switched colour for two districts]

I am unable to find the cause for such error. I have used [India District shape file](https://github.com/datameet/maps/tree/master/Districts/Census_2011). I have attached my code below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
## Creating data frame for map data
DISTRICT <- c("Agra","Aligarh","Allahabad","Ambedkar Nagar","Auraiya",
          "Azamgarh","Baghpat","Ballia","Balrampur","Banda","Bareilly",
          "Basti","Bijnor","Budaun","Bulandshahr","Chandauli",
          "Chitrakoot","Deoria","Etah","Etawah","Farrukhabad",
          "Fatehpur","Firozabad","Gautam Buddha Nagar","Ghaziabad",
          "Ghazipur","Gorakhpur","Hamirpur","Mahamaya Nagar","Jalaun",
          "Jaunpur","Jhansi","Jyotiba Phule Nagar","Kannauj",
          "Kanpur Dehat","Kanpur Nagar","Kansiram Nagar",
          "Kaushambi","Kushinagar","Lalitpur","Maharajganj","Mahoba",
          "Mainpuri","Mathura","Mau","Meerut","Mirzapur","Moradabad",
          "Muzaffarnagar","Pilibhit","Rampur","Saharanpur",
          "Sant Kabir Nagar","Sant Ravi Das Nagar(bhadohi)",
          "Shahjahanpur","Shrawasti","Siddharth Nagar",
          "Sonbhadra","Varanasi","Bahraich","Bara Banki",
          "Faizabad","Gonda","Hardoi","Kheri","Lucknow",
          "Pratapgarh","Rae Bareli","Sitapur","Sultanpur","Unnao")
ST_NM <- rep("Uttar Pradesh",71)
jr <- c(rep("Allahabad",59),rep("Lucknow",12))
reg.cases <- c(rep(156.29,59),rep(43.28,12))
map_data <- data.frame(DISTRICT,ST_NM,jr,reg.cases)

## Extracting state Uttar Pradesh (UP) from shape files
india.dist <- readShapeSpatial("./shapes2/2011_Dist.shp")
st.dat <- india.dist[india.dist$ST_NM== "Uttar Pradesh",]

## Creating ggplot object
st.dat1 <- st.dat
rownames(st.dat1@data) <- as.character(seq(1,NROW(st.dat1@data)))
st.dat1@data <- merge(st.dat1@data,map_data)#,by="DISTRICT")
##state@data$id <- rownames(state@data)
st.dat.fort <- tidy(st.dat1, region="DISTRICT")
sf1 <- merge(st.dat.fort, st.dat1@data, by.x="id", by.y="DISTRICT")

## Plotting
## Function used
label.breaks <- function(break.val){
  ##break.val <- c(0,10,50,100,500,1000)
  break.val <- c(break.val,Inf)
  loc.inf <- which(break.val%in%Inf)
  init.val <- break.val[1:(loc.inf-1)]
labs <- NULL
  for(i in 2:(loc.inf-1)){
    labs[i-1] <- paste(init.val[i-1],init.val[i]-1,sep="-")  
  } 
  labs <- c(labs,paste(break.val[loc.inf-1],"+",sep=""))
  return(labs)
}

break.val=c(0,25,50,100,150,200); palette="Reds"; legend.title="Reg.cases"
labs <- label.breaks(break.val)
bp.s <- cut(sf1$reg.cases, breaks=c(break.val,Inf), right=F,
        labels=labs)
p1 <- ggplot(data = sf1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group))
p1 <- p1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = bp.s)) + coord_map() + theme_grey()
p2 <- p1 + scale_fill_brewer(legend.title, palette  = palette)
p2 <- p2 + ylab("") + xlab("")
p2 <- p2 + expand_limits(x = sf1$long, y = sf1$lat)
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) + scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL)
p3 <- p2 + geom_path(data = st.dat, colour = "grey30", linetype=3,size= 0.1)

## Labelling with district names
cases.df <- get.centroid(st.dat, map_data)
dat <- merge(st.dat,map_data,by="DISTRICT")
idList <- dat@data$DISTRICT
centroids.df <- as.data.frame(coordinates(dat))
names(centroids.df) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude") 
reg.cases <- dat@data$reg.cases
cases.df <- data.frame(id = idList, cases = reg.cases, centroids.df)
p4 <- p3 + with(cases.df, annotate(geom="text", x = Longitude,
                               y = Latitude, label = id, size=filter.size))
ggsave(p4,file="trial_jr3.jpg")
```

Comment: When you examine `map.data` do the values in reg.cases correspond with the correct districts?

Comment: I have examined the map_data values correspond to correct districts.

Comment: Is it still consistent in sf1?

Comment: I made a minor correction in that line. It does give me consistent output for sf1.